# What is the meaning of "ironically" in this passage?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, irony

A rocket launched and shortly afterward exploded, on Tuesday. Below is passage from a news article written about it:

> This was the second launch attempt for the mission. Monday evening's try was thwarted by a stray sailboat in the rocket's danger zone–ironically, the restrictions are in case of just such an accident that occurred Tuesday.

Please explain to me how *ironically* is used here. I don't see any irony in restricting an area for safety purposes then it turns out that place was dangerous, due to the explosion. Is there another definition or perhaps the author meant something else that I'm missing?

Comment: "just such an accident that occurred "..this phrases lends credibility to the use of ironically. Ironically thus implies that though a risk assessment was already conducted and we had measures in place,still the accident occured. We knew it can happen,prepared ourselves so that it does not happen. Yet it happened.          Note: Irony deals with opposites; it has nothing to do with coincidence.

Comment: If the scheduled launch on *Monday* was thwarted by there being a sailboat in the ***danger zone***, that implies to me it was cancelled *to protect the sailboat, not the rocket*. I don't know (does anyone, *yet?*) why the rescheduled launch failed, but it may have something to do with the rescheduling. In which case it's somewhat ironic that the accident may have effectively been caused by following procedures intended to ***increase overall safety***. But a tiny risk reduction for a (relatively low value) sailboat may have led to a huge increase in risk for a very expensive rocket.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see! It would make sense if the scheduling caused the explosion. Right now they're still searching for the cause, though, so it's a bit early to say that.

Comment: @weakphoneme correct me if I'm wrong, but "the restrictions are in case of just such an accident" means that the safety guidelines are there for when there is an accident like that, not to prevent it right? 

I'm sure they have other guidelines for the prevention, but 'in case' reads like this particular restriction is there for the mishap chance an accident would happen. Then it wouldn't harm anyone that's in the danger zone.

Comment: It would be more ironic if the sailboat could somehow make this type of accident more likely, yet it happened when there was no sailboat. That's what the wording suggests, but it seems an unlikely causal relationship so I'm forced to rethink.

Answer (score 2):

Definitions of *irony* (and there are quite a few) emphasize the notion of incongruity—between something expected and something that comes to pass, for example, or between something said or done in a dramatic situation and how the action is understood by the audience. Here is the entry for *irony* in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **irony** *n* (1502) **1 :** a pretense of ignorance and of willingness to learn from another assumed in order to make the other's false conceptions conspicuous by adroit questioning — called also *Socratic irony* **2 a :** the use of words to express something other than and especially the opposite of the literal meaning **b :** a usually humorous or sardonic literary style or form characterized by irony **c :** an ironic expression or utterance **3 a (1) :**  incongruity between the actual result of a sequence of events and the normal or expected result **(2) :**  an event or result marked by such incongruity
>   **b :**  incongruity between a situation developed in a drama and the accompanying words or actions that is understood by the audience but not by the characters in the play — called also *dramatic irony*, *tragic irony*

It seems fairly clear than nothing in this entry makes *ironically* a good fit for the sentence quoted in the OP's question. So what was the intended word? I suspect that the author might have been looking for *coincidentally*. Again from the *Eleventh Collegiate*:

> **coincidentally** *adv* (1837) **1 :** in a coincidental manner : by coincidence {lonely singles who meet *coincidentally* and click — *People*} **2 :**  it is or seems coincidental that {*coincidentally*, the dog died exactly one year after his owner did}

In the example, there is a kind of coincidence in the fact that launch was delayed by an unsafe condition (the sailboat's presence in the rocket's danger zone) and the fact that the explosion of the rocket was precisely the kind of potentially disastrous occurrence that led the government to delay launches when the boats are in the area. But this is not a case of incongruity between launch policy and launch result; instead it's a clear case of congruity between the two. It follows that *ironically* is not a suitable word to describe the relationship between the launch delay and the launch explosion.

Comment: I'm with you, Sven Yargs. Having written a thesis on the rhetorical uses of irony, I am more familiar than most with the use and misuse of the various inflections of the word irony. In my experience, many people, including (especially?) newscasters are fond of using ironically rather than coincidentally. Perhaps they want to sound intelligent. There are, in fact, situational ironies, but the explosion of the rocket was not one of them. Don